# Performance issue with Add objects to Dictionary<dynamic, object>

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, dynamic, .net-4.0

Why is there a performance issue with Add objects (string OR Guid) to Dictionary<dynamic, object>?
Add objects to List< dynamic> significantly faster.

Dictionary<string, object> - not applicable because it uses x2.5 more RAM.

```
var guidPrefix = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-";
var rand = new Random();

var dictionary = new Dictionary<dynamic, object>();
var list = new List<dynamic>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    var guidOrAnyString = i.ToString().PadLeft(12, '0'); // Any string, NOT Guid
    if (rand.NextDouble() > 0.5)
        guidOrAnyString = guidPrefix + guidOrAnyString; // Guid
                               
    if (Guid.TryParse(guidOrAnyString, out var guid))
    {
        //list.Add(guid);
        dictionary.Add(guid, i);
    }
    else
    {
        //list.Add(guidOrAnyString);
        dictionary.Add(guidOrAnyString, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Dictionary<object, object> instead? That way you could at least know whether your issues are connected to using dynamic in this case.

Comment: how's a `Dictionary<byte[], object>` working? (in my experience, `dynamic` is _always_ a significant performance killer). also: mixing guids and _arbitrary strings_ seems a bad design choice in the first place.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Thank you the Dictionary<byte[], object> works very fast, this is a good solution.

Comment: @TobiasSchulte Dictionary<object, object> works slow the same as Dictionary<dynamic, object>.

Comment: Every time you use `dynamic` something in the world has its life extinguished by hard to find and diagnose runtime errors and slow performance. Essentially always check when you use this feature you are not solving a problem by creating 2 more other problems